# How to get price of asset with nordnet api?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I'm trying to get price of asset using get request to `https://www.nordnet.fi/api/2/instruments/price/16256554`, where `16256554` is something like an asset id. I'm expecting to get this response:

```
ask: 776.5
ask_volume: 387142
bid: 776.5
bid_volume: 385982
close: 770
delay: 0
high: 784
instrument_id: 16256554
last: 776.5
last_volume: 4863
lot_size: 1
low: 772.3
open: 778.7
tick_timestamp: 1660576800019
trade_timestamp: 1660576800018
turnover: 959405065.4
turnover_volume: 1234170
vwap: 777.4
```

But it returns only

```
{
    "code": "NEXT_INVALID_SESSION"
}
```

I found out that it requires `Cookie: SHAREVILLE=0915f43e60162f92dea7f7c7813422148e7xxxxx` in headers. So my question is: where can I get this `Cookie` without using webdriver?

Comment: Can you share the main url meaning the thml content url?

Comment: @F.Hoque, https://shareville.fi/osakkeet/novo-nordisk-b-as

Comment: How can we see your expected data from this url?

Comment: @F.Hoque I want to get asset's price

Comment: @F.Hoque https://imgur.com/a/emRQ67v, this request

Comment: you may have to first send normal GET to main page and it should send back response with cookies in headers - `response.cookies`. And next you should copy this value to next requests. OR simply use `requests.Session()` and it should automatically copy cookies from one request to another.

Comment: BTW: API requets usually are send by JavaScript as `AJAX`/`XHR` request - and some server may check if request has header `'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'`

Comment: @furas will it return needed cookie `SHAREVILLE`?

Comment: In many pages it work but it seems this page has more complex system to stop bots/scripts/hackers and I can't find this value in any other requests - probably it uses JavaScript to generate this value. It may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.